# Database Table Design guidance

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating a table of pilots with the following fields, would there be any advantage to breaking the table down at each category shown into separate tables and link via the pilots primary key in a one to one relationship?

```
PILOT PROFILE
    username
    password
  BASIC INFO
    first_name
    last_name
    email
    date_of_birth
    address_line1
    address_line2
    town_city
    county
    postcode
    country
    tel_no
    mobile_no
  MEDICAL INFO
    med_class
    med_issued
    med_special
    med_verified
    med_verified_date
    med_verified_by
  LICENCE INFO
    licence_number
    licence_type
    licence_tailwheel
    licence_retractableGear
    licence_vpProp
    licence_turboCharged
    licence_cabinPressurisation
    licence_sep_L
    licence_sep_S
    licence_mep_L
    licence_mep_S
    licence_tmg
    licence_night
    licence_imc
    licence_ir
    licence_fi
    licence_fe
    licence_other
    licence_verified
    licence_verified_date
    licence_verified_by
  FLIGHT EXPERIENCE
    home_airport
    hours_total
    hours_pic
    hours_in12months
    hours_verified
    hours_verified_date
    hours_verified_by
  PAYMENT
    paid_date
```

Comment: Around a couple of thousand, but likely under 10,000 records. Data will be accessed once when a pilot logs in or when a club searches for a pilot then they will look at the pilots info. Sorry could you also explain the term "horizontally silo", i think I can work it out from the context but just to be sure ;-) thanks

Comment: That term was obtuse. Just meant what you were asking in terms of breaking up data for 1:1 use across multiple tables. Entered an answer according to scale info provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** Don't break up the row data in this context.

For reasons of performance at scale, sometimes it makes sense to break a table 1:1 into other tables, but given the information provided, this will absolutely not be necessary.

*However*, on a per-query basis, please do `SELECT` only the fields needed. Meaning: instead of using `SELECT *` at whim, use something like `SELECT username, password FROM pilot`. Side note: don't store your passwords clear text :)